# Capture reason for failure of 'Test-Json' when using a try/catch block

Tags: json, powershell, exception, jsonschema, powershell-core

In PowerShell I am validating some JSON against a schema using the `Test-Json` cmdlet. When the JSON is invalid against the schema, details are printed on the screen. However, if the `Test-Json` command is wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block those details are lost.

For example...

```
Test-Json -Json $json -Schema $schema
```

if this test fails but there is no `try`/`catch` block you could expect to see something similar to this (taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7)) -

```
Test-Json : IntegerExpected: #/age
At line:1 char:37
+ "{'name': 'Ashley', 'age': '25'}" | Test-Json -Schema $schema
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Json], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidJsonAgainstSchema,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestJsonCommand
False
```

However, add a `try`/`catch` block and now I'm unable to get the actual underlying reason for the failure - `IntegerExpected: #/age`.

```
try
{
    Test-Json -Json $json -Schema $schema
}
catch
{
    throw $_.Exception.Message
}
```

> The JSON is not valid with the schema.

In this case there is no inner exception - `$_.Exception.InnerException.Message`. And there is no additional data with the exception - `$_.Exception.Data`

Is it possible to retrieve the details of the test failure when catching an error?

Comment: In the `catch` have you tried `$_ | gm` or `$_ | fl`?

Comment: @NekoMusume - Bingo, `$_.ErrorDetails.Message` has the relevant details. Thanks.